# After using foreach() the same database table values are repeated again and again

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a model where I have joined two tables and have selected some table values, I am then passing it on to my controller and from the controller I am passing it on to the view page. In the view page I am using foreach() to fetch the values and then I am displaying it. But the problem is the same table row is getting repeated again and again.

Model

```
public function image_list()
{ 
  $this->db->select('interior_testing.type_id,interior_testing.profile_pic, interior_testing.type, interior_testing.location, interior_testing.name, interior_image_testing.image_path');
  $this->db->from('interior_testing');
  $q=$this->db->join('interior_image_testing', 'interior_image_testing.type_id = interior_testing.type_id');
  $this->db->where('interior_testing.category_id', 3);
  $q = $this->db->get();
  return $q->result();  
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->load->model("Interior_listing_model","interior");
    $data['particles'] = $this->interior->image_list();

    // Load Interior Listing View
    $this->load->view("interior/interior",$data);
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($particles as $particle): ?> 
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6 workimg">
    <img src="assets/img/<?= $particle->image_path ?> " width="100%"> 
  </div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are You trying `$this->db->get_compiled_select('interior_testing')`?

Comment: No, I am just trying to fetch the database table value, which I have got after joining the two tables.

Comment: The code above  is the function that You need to print, cause this function print the query You trying to send to backend and database

Comment: Actually, I need the image_path, which I am getting from the query result, now I am using it here in the view page <img src="assets/img/<?= $particle->image_path ?> " width="100%"> , to get the images, but the same image is getting repeated again and again.

Comment: is the loop generate `img` infinitely?

Comment: No, just 7 times

Comment: maybe, because you have 7 similar items in Your `db`???

Comment: No there is just one entry in the database table.

Comment: Time to go looking... In your index method, just before you show your view - what does var_dump($data); give you?

Comment: try this : `print_r($particles);` it's will print Your data from `db`

Comment: I am getting an array where it has an image path, its name along with its other information but this entry is there 7 times, the same information.

Comment: So you have to take a look at your database and your query. Is it the case where you will get the same image? Just after your $this->db->get you can echo $this->db->last_query(); - cope the result and play with that in... are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: okay, yes I am using phpmyadmin. And no, it is not like that, I don't intend to get the same image.

Comment: I'm suspecting `fetchAll` to be the culprit

Comment: Ok so take the generated SQL and use it in phpmyadmin. Without knowing your table structure and values for this case, it's hard for us to see whats going on.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your suggestions were of great help indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean up your query like below and if that doesnt work You may need to add a group_by id to your query

```
public function image_list()
{ 
$select = "it.type_id, it.profile_pic, it.type, it.location, it.name, im.image_path";

return $this->db->select($select)
//equivalent to name as abr
->join('interior_image_testing im', 'im.type_id = it.type_id');
->where('it.category_id', 3);
//equivalent to name as abr
->get('interior_testing it')->result();

}
```